# Google maps external marker link

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps and trying to make some external link markers.  I'm loading it with async and then trying to make markers that have external links that can then be clicked on to animate to the markers.  What I have isn't quite working, but I think it's close.  I was also wondering how to do this w/ jquery?  I think part of the issue is I don't have access to the body tag so I can't do  and I'm not sure how to otherwise do it.

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;



var marker1;
var marker2;

function initialize() { 
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.032260, 50.514686); 
var myOptions = { 
  zoom: 15, 
  center: latlng, 
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 

marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new 
google.maps.LatLng(41.569690, 2.257090), map: map, title: 'Barcelona' }); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() { 
  infowindow.setContent('Spanish Grand Prix'); 
  infowindow.open(map, marker1); 
}); 

marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new 
google.maps.LatLng(31.338463, 121.220355), map: map, title: 'Shanghai'}); 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() { 
  infowindow.setContent('Chinese Grand Prix'); 
  infowindow.open(map, marker2); 
}); 
}
```

Comment: How come you don't have access to the body tag and what do you mean by 'animate the markers' (I've seen some examples in which the markers 'dance'. Are you looking for something like it?)?

Comment: sorry that was unclear, I don't have access to it because the company is using a content management system that blocks this access, which is why I can't use a jquery map script.  The department wants this feature anyways so this is why.  By animate I mean you click the link and the maps moves to that marker.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can use any of the Maps plugins, like the ones stated in this link and many others:

http://slodive.com/web-development/15-jquery-google-map-plugins/

Comment: sorry that was unclear, I don't have access to it because the company is using a content management system that blocks this access, which is why I can't use a jquery map script.  The department wants this feature anyways so this is why.  By animate I mean you click the link and the maps moves to that marker.